# openssl upgrade from 0.9.8w to 0.9.8y

Tags: openssl, upgrade

I am trying to upgrade the openssl version from 0.9.8w to 0.9.8 y to address the following security vulnerabilities CVE-2012-2333, CVE-2013-0166 , CVE-2013-0169.

While trying to upgrade I am facing following dependanices and any insight to this will be highly appreciated.

```
[root@CAM store]# openssl version
OpenSSL 0.9.8w 23 Apr 2012
[root@CAM store]# rpm -qa | grep openssl
openssl-0.9.8e-22.el5
openssl-0.9.8w-1
[root@CAM store]# rpm -Uvh openssl-0.9.8y-1.i386.rpm
error: Failed dependencies:
        libcrypto.so.6 is needed by (installed) m2crypto-0.16-8.el5.i386
        libcrypto.so.6 is needed by (installed) python-libs-2.4.3-46.el5.i386
        libcrypto.so.6 is needed by (installed) openldap-2.3.43-25.el5.i386
        libcrypto.so.6 is needed by (installed) net-snmp-libs-5.3.2.2-17.el5.i386
        libcrypto.so.6 is needed by (installed) postgresql-libs-8.1.23-1PGDG.rhel5.i386
        libcrypto.so.6 is needed by (installed) bind-libs-9.3.6-20.P1.el5.i386
        libcrypto.so.6 is needed by (installed) curl-7.15.5-15.el5.i386
        libcrypto.so.6 is needed by (installed) libnasl2-2.2.11-27.el5.i386
        libcrypto.so.6 is needed by (installed) nmap-4.11-2.i386
        libcrypto.so.6 is needed by (installed) wget-1.11.4-2.el5_4.1.i386
        libcrypto.so.6 is needed by (installed) nessus-server-2.2.11-27.el5.i386
        libcrypto.so.6 is needed by (installed) cyrus-sasl-2.1.22-5.el5_4.3.i386
        libcrypto.so.6 is needed by (installed) bind-utils-9.3.6-20.P1.el5.i386
        libcrypto.so.6 is needed by (installed) neon-0.25.5-10.el5_4.1.i386
        libcrypto.so.6 is needed by (installed) openldap-clients-2.3.43-25.el5.i386
        libcrypto.so.6 is needed by (installed) cyrus-sasl-md5-2.1.22-5.el5_4.3.i386
        libcrypto.so.6 is needed by (installed) stunnel-4.15-2.el5.1.i386
        libcrypto.so.6 is needed by (installed) distcache-1.4.5-14.1.i386
        libcrypto.so.6 is needed by (installed) tcpdump-3.9.4-15.el5.i386
        libcrypto.so.6 is needed by (installed) ntp-4.2.2p1-15.el5.centos.1.i386
        libcrypto.so.6 is needed by (installed) net-snmp-5.3.2.2-17.el5.i386
        libcrypto.so.6 is needed by (installed) fipscheck-1.2.0-1.el5.i386
        libcrypto.so.6 is needed by (installed) net-snmp-utils-5.3.2.2-17.el5.i386
        libcrypto.so.6 is needed by (installed) postgresql-8.1.23-1PGDG.rhel5.i386
        libcrypto.so.6 is needed by (installed) postgresql-server-8.1.23-1PGDG.rhel5.i386
        libcrypto.so.6 is needed by (installed) postgresql-contrib-8.1.23-1PGDG.rhel5.i386
        libcrypto.so.6 is needed by (installed) cavium-1.0-7.i386
        libssl.so.6 is needed by (installed) m2crypto-0.16-8.el5.i386
        libssl.so.6 is needed by (installed) python-libs-2.4.3-46.el5.i386
        libssl.so.6 is needed by (installed) openldap-2.3.43-25.el5.i386
        libssl.so.6 is needed by (installed) postgresql-libs-8.1.23-1PGDG.rhel5.i386
        libssl.so.6 is needed by (installed) curl-7.15.5-15.el5.i386
        libssl.so.6 is needed by (installed) libnasl2-2.2.11-27.el5.i386
        libssl.so.6 is needed by (installed) nmap-4.11-2.i386
        libssl.so.6 is needed by (installed) wget-1.11.4-2.el5_4.1.i386
        libssl.so.6 is needed by (installed) nessus-server-2.2.11-27.el5.i386
        libssl.so.6 is needed by (installed) neon-0.25.5-10.el5_4.1.i386
        libssl.so.6 is needed by (installed) quota-3.13-5.el5.i386
        libssl.so.6 is needed by (installed) openldap-clients-2.3.43-25.el5.i386
        libssl.so.6 is needed by (installed) stunnel-4.15-2.el5.1.i386
        libssl.so.6 is needed by (installed) distcache-1.4.5-14.1.i386
        libssl.so.6 is needed by (installed) postgresql-8.1.23-1PGDG.rhel5.i386
        libssl.so.6 is needed by (installed) postgresql-server-8.1.23-1PGDG.rhel5.i386
        libssl.so.6 is needed by (installed) postgresql-contrib-8.1.23-1PGDG.rhel5.i386
```

Thanks,
Vetrichelvan.G

Answer (score 3):

I don't know where you got that RPM from (since you don't tell us), but you have a problem already:

```
[root@CAM store]# rpm -qa | grep openssl
openssl-0.9.8e-22.el5
openssl-0.9.8w-1
```

Someone has brute-forced a second OpenSSL RPM onto your system, in addition to the RedHat-provided one, probably as an incorrect response to an earlier OpenSSL issue.

You don't need to upgrade the version of openssl to stay securely-patched.  You need to get rid of weird non-distro versions, and keep up with Red Hat's patches to EL5 (as long as it's in support).  That will mean that your version of openssl-0.9.8e will stay patched, and even though the OpenSSL version number won't change, the RPM version will.

You may find [this answer](https://serverfault.com/questions/535606/is-there-a-big-difference-between-centos-6-4-to-6-2-and-should-i-up-down-grade/535615#535615) sheds more light on the way Red Hat backport patches to fix vulnerabilities, instead of constantly bumping application version numbers.

Comment: I hadn't done the upgrade of openssl version from 0.9.8e - 0.9.8w also I have created openssl 0.9.8y rpm by using it's source and spec file.   Are you saying there might be issues with the 0.9.8e - 0.9.8w upgrade itself also can I address the mentioned vulnerabilities as a patch in versions 0.9.8e or 0.9.8w

Comment: I'm saying that you need to understand why the 0.9.8w version is there at all, and if it's not a really good reason, rip it out - and make sure the RH version is properly back in place.  Then, simply doing a `yum update` should take the RH version of 0.9.8e to a suitably-patched one.