# Downgrade centos version

Tags: centos

I currently have CentOS 5.10 installed in my server.

Is it possible to downgrade it to CentOS 5.5 with out re installing ?

Comment: Before you go any further with this, you should think carefully about what you're doing, because **there is no unique thing you can call CentOS 5.5** (or indeed 5.10) so it makes very little sense to try to downgrade to it.  [My answer here](http://serverfault.com/a/535615/55514) explains this more fully, but in short, there is *no* good reason for what you are trying to do, and a lot of reasons why it's a very bad idea.

Comment: my client wants it and I couldnt make him understand and I dont have KVM access to my server so cant install from iso.

Comment: It will be very painful.  You will have to do much of it by hand.  It will therefore cost him a lot of money.  And at the end of the day, all he'll have is a highly insecure system.  Try that.

Comment: There is absolutely no way you should ever allow this to happen. If the client asks for it, your job as a professional is to refuse.

Answer (score 2):

I don't have a CentOS test box at hand, but the procedure is documented on Red Hat's support portal https://access.redhat.com/solutions/186763

1. Ensure that you have a yum repo for that old release configured. Check http://mirror.centos.org/centos/5.5/readme to see it is considered a bad idea to run CentOS 5.5 and where to find such repo's.
2. Install the correct old kernel for that old minor release,

   `yum install kernel-<version>`
3. `reboot` to that kernel version.
4. And than run a `yum downgrade` to the release package you want, something like: `yum downgrade centos-release-5-5`

No personal experience if doing the above will work as expected...