# How can I force CentOS to version 6.6?

Tags: centos6, netinstall

I have a production server on a cloud service that runs 64-bit CentOS version 6.6. I'm setting up a local testing server that I want to have all the same software versions. I have installed CentOS via the netinstall blob and it ended up with the 6.7 version. How can I force it to be 6.6?

Comment: You should probably use CentOS 6.7. Is there a reason for you to pin the OS at an older point release?

Comment: Well, only that my production server runs CentOS 6.6.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a big difference between CentOS 6.4 to 6.2 and should I up/down-grade?](http://serverfault.com/questions/535606/is-there-a-big-difference-between-centos-6-4-to-6-2-and-should-i-up-down-grade)

Answer (score 2):

The point release of 6.6 is no longer in the main repos.  You would have to access or mirror the vault repo, then modify your yum and kickstart configurations to explicity use that version.

Folks will likely suggest you should not be building/tracking a specific point release and to use the latest, but I'm going to assume you understand the risks of staying on an unsupported point release that has been deprecated.

See http://vault.centos.org/6.6/ for the older versions of the packages.

Comment: Basically... pinning the release usually isn't a good thing. But this is one way to do it.

Comment: I completely agree ewwhite.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the 64-bit here `http://vault.centos.org/6.6/isos/x86_64/` or the 32-bit here `http://vault.centos.org/6.6/isos/i386/`

I will advice to go with minimal iso, but if you prefer netinstall then

64-bit netinstall iso `http://vault.centos.org/6.6/isos/x86_64/CentOS-6.6-x86_64-netinstall.iso`

32-bit netinstall iso `http://vault.centos.org/6.6/isos/i386/CentOS-6.6-i386-netinstall.iso`