# Migrating haproxy from 1.5 to 1.7

Tags: haproxy

Both versions are stable but Linux distributions mostly contain 1.5 (CentOS 7.3 for example)

I think about compiling haproxy from source and providing RPMs for the servers I administer using [this][1] approach.
I understand why distros with longterm support tend to support older versions of packages.

So I try to find the middle way between being on the bleeding edge when compiling haproxy on my own and having support and automatic updates through the package manager.
haproxy 1.5 will be the next release that moves to "critical updates only", that made me think I better jump to a current release.

When I decide to use haproxy 1.5 and either make the automatic shift to 1.6 (or whatever other version) as soon as RHEL/CentOS decides to move: what will be the steps needed to migrate ? Is this just some minor modifications in the config file ? Or are there some "breaking" changes to be expected ?

Comment: It depends which features you need: If 1.5 provides all of them, use the package.

Comment: @HBruijn while the question you marked contains a generic reply it doesn't answer my question that is focused on haproxy. I am no expert in haproxy and I would have expected some answer which points out advantages / disadvantages. 1.7 for example has a better reload mechanism it would "like" to have, but I don't "need" it.

Comment: You already linked to the change log and read the release notes. In short: **only you can determine if you *really need* those new features** and if the effort is worth it.  We can't really add anything more to that. Hence a generic duplicate. -  RHEL 7 was probably released (long) before HAProxy 1.7 was deemed ready. HAproxy is in this regard not more interesting than other packages.

Comment: The fact that [enterprise linux distributions have old(ish) versions](https://serverfault.com/a/535615/37681) of all kinds of software is the price you pay for long term stability and support, but that does not mean that you will suffer from known bugs and security  vulnerabilities resolved in new releases.

Comment: @HBruijn To _me_ haproxy is more interesting than other packages ;-) I will make another attempt by edition my question with a concrete detail.

Comment: @HBruijn: is my question now more fit and legit for having the duplicate marker removed ?